How to resolve "Use a different version of dependency"?
Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against codename "Tiramisu" of the
Android APIs.
  :app is currently compiled against android-34.

  Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.0-alpha01',
  or set compileSdkPreview to "Tiramisu" in your build.gradle
  file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

I tried to compile, but it's giving me the error above. How can I resolve this?

You seem to be using an outdated version of the androidx.activity:activity-compose library. You should be using version 1.9.0 right now, or the latest version according to the official release docs
If you have a reason to keep using the older version (which I don't advise), you'll also have to downgrade your Android compileSdk version from 34 also.
